# How to use phone gap in windows phone 7 mobile application development?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am iphone and android developer.I know how to use phone gap for iphone app and android app development.But I am new for windows phone 7 app development using phonegap.I dont know how to start windows phone 7 application development using phone gap.

Please give me advice for this query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like PhoneGap doesn't support Windows Phone yet.

This post seems to suggest its close though and there is an alpha/beta you can start developing
http://programmersgoodies.com/phonegap-for-windows-phone-7

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap support for Windows Phone 7 is still in a "pre-alpha" state.
From a practical stand it's not realistic to start developing with it. Some people have started (and apparently submitted apps based on it) but there is no guarantee of future compatibility with what they've done.

When available, it will also only support phones running Mango.